# Dynamic model in Nhibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I use Dynamic model in Nhibernate. 
Like this :

```
<class entity-name="Customer">

    <id name="id"
        type="long"
        column="ID">
        <generator class="sequence"/>
    </id>

    <property name="name"
        column="NAME"
        type="string"/>

    <property name="address"
        column="ADDRESS"
        type="string"/>

    <many-to-one name="organization"
        column="ORGANIZATION_ID"
        class="Organization"/>

    <bag name="orders"
        inverse="true"
        lazy="false"
        cascade="all">
        <key column="CUSTOMER_ID"/>
        <one-to-many class="Order"/>
    </bag>

</class>
```

I use HQL for queries. 
I don't want perform select * all time. 
How can I say to Nhibernate which fields return  . 
But I need the result in Idictionary where key is name from HBM
thanks .

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
IQuery CustomerQuery = session.CreateQuery("select Name from TABLE where Id= :id")
                              .SetInt32("id", 1983056);
IList result = CustomerQuery.List();
```

So above I restrict the number of columns retrieved and will retrieve only 1 row where the Id matches.

The concept is called 'Projection'.  Good luck!

Comment: IQuery CustomerQuery = session.CreateQuery("from Customer where Id= :id") .SetInt32("id", 1983056); IList result = CustomerQuery.List(); I have dictionary with keys like my property name . In your example I have List of integers. with out names

Comment: @Sveta, if you need a strongly typed result from a projected query, perhaps you can use a DTO.